# More efficient way than iterrows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have a `DataFrame` df with columns `action` and `pointerID`. In the code snippet below I'm iterating through every row which is pretty inefficient because the DataFrame is pretty large. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
annotated = []
curr_pointers = []
count = 1
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    action = row["action"]
    id = row["pointerID"]
    if action == "ACTION_MOVE":
        annotated.append(curr_pointers[id])
    elif (action == "ACTION_POINTER_DOWN") or (action == "ACTION_DOWN"):
        if row["actionIndex"] != id:
            continue

        if id >= len(curr_pointers):
            curr_pointers.append(count)
        else:
            curr_pointers[id] = count
        annotated.append(count)
        count = count + 1
    elif (action == "ACTION_POINTER_UP") or (action == "ACTION_UP") or (action == "ACTION_CANCEL"):
        if row["actionIndex"] != id:
            continue

        annotated.append(curr_pointers[id])
    else:
        print("{} unknown".format(action))
```

Comment: What does your function do?

Comment: Please add an input/output example and some text to explain what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `df.apply`, arrange the contents of the loop as a function, for example, `def some_actions(action, pointerID, actionIndex)`.
Then you could use

```
df.apply(
    lambda x: some_actions(x['action'], x['PointerID'], x['actionIndex']), 
    axis=1
)
```

Theoretically, it should work faster.